# What is the server discovery endpoint (well-known url) of a AWS Cognito Userpool?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools, ibm-api-management

OpenID providers publish their metadata at a well-known URL. In Okta it looks something like this: ***https://dev-599740.okta.com/oauth2/default/.well-known/oauth-authorization-server***
Is there a similar URL for a AWS Cognito user pool? if not how do I find out the following endpoints of a AWS Cognito userpool?

1. Client Registration Endpoint
2. Introspection Endpoint
3. Token Revoke Endpoint

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Format of a well-know URL for a specific AWS Cognito Userpool is as follows  : *https://cognito-idp.[region].amazonaws.com/[userPoolId]/.well-known/openid-configuration*

Comment: Thanks for that! Is it also possible to retriev the public certificate, which Cognito uses to sign its JWT? I need that for offline validation of my JWT at hand.

Comment: Ah found it: https://cognito-idp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/xxx/.well-known/jwks.json